# From 4 into 2 quadrant - battery simulator on LT1970

Tags: batteries, simulation

I am trying to understand the possibility of modifying of this circuit in order to have only two quadrant to avoid using the bipolar power supply, will this be possible with LT1970?

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you want to do. Is it a analogue multiplication with bipolar transistors?

Comment: I would like to use this circuit as a starting point in order to create battery cell simulator, only two quadrants will be needed.